# How to handle mouse events captured from QGraphicsView and QGraphicsItem at the same time?

Tags: c++, qt, events

In this code I need to perform different actions in `mousePressEvent(..)` of `Item` and `customGraphicsView`. redefinition of mouse events handlers in `QGraphicsView` inherited class interfere with that of `QGraphicsItem` how to separate the action of clicking `Item` and `view` so that they can give a different behaviour?.

```
class CustomGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView 
{
...
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
};
```

---

```
class Item: public QGraphicsItem
{
protected:
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
};
```

---

```
class customWidget: public QWidget 
{
public:
customWidget(QWidget * parent = 0) ;
...
private:
    customGraphicsView * view ;
    Item * item ;
};
```

---

```
customWidget::customWidget(QWidget* parent)
    :QWidget(parent)
{
view = new customGraphicsView(this) ;
item = new item; 

view->addItem(item) ;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to understand the event handling between the QGraphicsView, the QGraphicsScene, and any items in the scene. QGraphicsView gets the events first, translates them into scene events, and then the scene passes them off to the appropriate item. If you're not seeing an event where you expect, it's probably because you're intercepting it elsewhere first. I find that it's very useful to put debug statements into each of the event handlers so that I can see where the event came in and where it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

thank for your answers, but i had to remove QGraphicsItem mouse event and implement the code through QGraphicsView only like this

```
void CustomGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    Item * pressedItem ;

    pressPoint = event->pos();

    if(scene())
    {
        if (!items().isEmpty())
        {
            QPointF scenePoint = mapToScene(event->pos()) ;

            QGraphicsItem * item = scene()->itemAt(scenePoint, transform());


            if(pressedItem = dynamic_cast<Item*>(item))
            {
                //code for item press, instead of using QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
                 pressedItem->setColor(Qt::red); 
           }
        }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**At first**, you should use `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` instead of `QMouseEvent`
 for QGraphicsItem.

**Then** write your own implementation for each `mousePressEvent` like:

```
void Item::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
   QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
// do everything you was going to
}
```

and

```
void CustomGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
   QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
// do everything you was going to
}
```